# Partition scheme change with clustered Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table which has 600 million records and also has the Partition on PS_TRPdate(TRPDate) column, I want to change it to another Partition PS_LPDate(LPDate).

So I have tried with small amount of data with following steps.
1) Drop the Primary key Constraints.
2) Adding the New Primary Key Clustered Index with new Partition PS_LPDate(LPDate).

Is it Feasible with 600 million records? Can anyone guide me for it? 
and How does it works with Non Partitioned Tables?

--343

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to change the partition?

Comment: u know we have partition on TRPdate which not used by user and they mostly use LPDate.

Answer (score 2):

My gut feeling is that you should create a parallel table using a new primary key, file groups and files.

To test out my assumption, I looked at a [old blog post](http://craftydba.com/?p=2765) in which I stored the first five million prime numbers into three files / file groups.

I used the TSQL view that [Kalen Delaney](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/07/26/my-big-fat-partitioning-query.aspx) wrote and I modified to my standards to look at the partition information.

As you can see, we have three partitions based on the primary key.

[image]

Next, I drop the primary key on the my_value column, create a new column named chg_value, update it to the prime number, and then try to create a new primary key.

```
-- drop primary key (pk)
alter table tbl_primes drop constraint [PK_TBL_PRIMES]

-- add new field for new pk
alter table tbl_primes add chg_value bigint not null default (0)

-- update new field
update tbl_primes set chg_value = my_value

-- try to add a new primary key
alter table tbl_primes add constraint [PK_TBL_PRIMES] primary key (chg_value)
```

First, I was surprise that the partition still stayed together after dropping the PK.  However, the view shows the index no longer exists.

[image]

Second, I end up receiving the following error during constraint creation.

[image]

While you could merge/switch the partitions into one file group which is not part of the scheme, drop/create the primary key, partition function & partition scheme, and then move the data yet again with the appropriate merge/switch statements, I would not.

This will generate a ton of work (TSQL) and cause alot of I/O on the disks.

I suggest you build a parallel partitioned table, if you have space, with the new primary key.  Reload the data from the old table to the new.

If you are not using data compression and have the enterprise version of SQL Server, why not save the bytes by turning it on.

Good luck!

John

**www.craftydba.com**

Comment: Thanks John...Appreciate your Help. I have tried to drop index and recreate as you mentioned with almost 20 Million records in one table and It was took almost 4 min but I want an answer for 600 Million record, If I do the same exercise, how much time it will take? and these exercise will perform in production. on top of that I have almost 183 tables among them, max records 629 million and min 84 million. I want the feasibility for 600 Million records partition change.

Comment: For me, it all depends upon disk size.  Larger the size, longer the time to make the change as we know.  Also, what is the comment about 183 tables.  Are all the tables partitioned?  Or are they just on the primary file group?

Comment: out of 183 tables some table have partitioned and some doesn't have. all together database size almost 1.5 terabyte.

Comment: Okay, Is there any reason you can not rebuild the 629 million row table in parallel?  Call it [new_table_name] if you need it in the same database.  Use new file groups, new files, one new tables with updated PK, and new partition function/schema.  Use a synonym for the production cut over.  Drop the old table at that time.

Comment: Also, if you can.  Use data compression.  I had the same issue with a 4 TB table and was able to reduce it to 500 GB.  However, it comes at the hefty enterprise version price!